# How to show input language indicator when a input field is focused?

Tags: macos, automator, language, input-source, text-input

### Problem

I type in multiple languages and it bothers me that I have to correct my input if the keyboard is not my expected language. Looking up the input source in the menu bar is not convenient for me.

[image: 1]

### Question

Is it possible for the indicator to show up when an input field is focused? Alternatively, is there a way to set up an automation script when an input field is focused?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean by an input field? Any place in any program where you can type something?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible for the indicator to show up but the following is just a side effect of changing the input source.

Press and hold <kbd>⌃</kbd> + <kbd>␣</kbd> (control+space). Input source change pop-up window will appear. To navigate/change input source keep holding control and release and press the space to move. Alternatively hold control and repeatedly press space. After selecting new input source (or keeping existing) indicator is displayed briefly.

Comment: This is helpful. It is what I would like to achieve with a script, for simulating the key code to wake up the indicator. All I need is a way to trigger it when an input field is focused.